# sklearn LogisticRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, probability, logistic-regression

I trained a LogisticRegression model from sklearn.linear_model. I did two tests with the exact same data (both for training and testing). In one test the data was read from local csv file. In the other test data was received from network socket. However, I got different prediction probability results from predict_proba output.

Is there any possible reason that can explain this issue? Or there must be some kind of problem with the code? I am using Python 3.4.4 and the scikit-learn version is 0.18.1.

Thanks!

Some updates:

There was an issue with data precision, so that there was difference between two data sources. Now I round to 5 decimal points while reading CSV file and also round to 5 decimals for network data. I double checked that data are exactly the same now - both for training set (I checked first and last row) and test data. However, I still see different prediction probability results. Are there any other possible reasons? Network socket is serial and there should be no order issue.

Comment: It's possible that the CSV file has a limited precision (i.e. is cutting off at 6 decimal places, for example) while the data over the network socket is full precision. This could cause a difference.

Comment: Alternatively, make sure that in both cases you are reading ALL the lines (check the the first and last rows are read in each case). Also, if your network socket implementation is not serial (i.e. coming in a different order) than maybe you are missing some.

Comment: There can be a large number of possibilities for this to happen. Show some code to identify them. Also are you setting the random seed (`random_state`) parameter?

Comment: There was an issue with data precision, so that there was difference between two data sources. Now I round to 5 decimal points while reading CSV file and also round to 5 decimals for network data. I double checked that data are exactly the same now - both for training set (I checked first and last row) and test data. However, I still see different prediction probability results. Are there any other possible reasons? Network socket is serial and there should be no order issue.